# How to make bazel generate temporary static libs when bazel build //

Tags: tensorflow, bazel, tensorflow-serving

I'm using bazel to build tensorflow and tensorflow/serving, usually when I built tensorflow/serving with bazel, bazel generated some static library in `bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/core/` for me.
for example, after I successfully built tensorflow/serving, I got `bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/core/libaspired_version_policy.a` and so on.

But things changed when building tensorflow/serving on another docker instance, under `bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/core/` I only got `_objs`, no static libraries anymore, how come?

What should I do to get these static libraries?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:1.15.5-py3
LABEL version="1.0.0"
WORKDIR /root/
ENV TMP=/tmp
RUN export https_proxy=http://220.181.102.178:8118 && \
  export http_proxy=http://220.181.102.178:8118
RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/gfortran /usr/bin/gfortran
RUN apt-get update -yq ; exit 0
RUN apt-get install -yq software-properties-common apt-utils && apt-get update -yq; exit 0
RUN apt-get install -yq vim tree clang gdb make git
RUN apt-get install -yq automake bison flex libboost-all-dev libevent-dev
RUN apt-get install -yq libssl-dev ssh libtool pkg-config
RUN apt-get install -yq default-jdk default-jre libunwind8-dev libc-ares-dev
RUN apt-get install -yq python-numpy python-future libleveldb-dev libsnappy-dev libgoogle-perftools-dev
RUN apt-get install -yq librdkafka-dev libapr1-dev libaprutil1-dev texinfo unzip zip
RUN unset TF_NEED_CUDA
## To install go, uncomment below
#RUN add-apt-repository ppa:longsleep/golang-backports -y
#RUN apt-get install -yq golang-go 
RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test -y
RUN apt-get install -yq gcc-8 g++-8
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-8 80 \
      --slave /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-8 \
      --slave /usr/bin/gcc-ar gcc-ar /usr/bin/gcc-ar-8 \
      --slave /usr/bin/gcc-nm gcc-nm /usr/bin/gcc-nm-8 \
      --slave /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib gcc-ranlib /usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-8
RUN export https_proxy=http://220.181.102.178:8118 && wget https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.18.5/cmake-3.18.5-Linux-x86_64.sh && \
    bash cmake-3.18.5-Linux-x86_64.sh --prefix=/usr/ --skip-license && \
    rm -rf cmake-3.18.5-Linux-x86_64.sh
RUN export https_proxy=http://220.181.102.178:8118 && wget https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases/download/0.24.1/bazel-0.24.1-installer-linux-x86_64.sh && \
    bash bazel-0.24.1-installer-linux-x86_64.sh && rm -rf bazel-0.24.1-installer-linux-x86_64.sh
RUN mkdir .ssh/
ADD .ssh/ .ssh/
ADD .vimrc .
ADD .bashrc .
RUN export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:$PATH && export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
RUN git config --global credential.helper store
```

bazel version : 0.24.1

tensorflow/serving version : 1.15.0 downloaded from github release page.

build command :

```
export https_proxy=http://10.130.48.179:3128
unset TF_NEED_CUDA

# Build tensorflow_model_server
bazel build -c opt --copt=-msse4.1 --copt=-msse4.2 --copt=-mavx --copt=-mavx2 --copt=-mfma --copt=-O3 --copt=-march=native --cxxopt="-fexceptions" --verbose_failures //tensorflow_serving/model_servers:tensorflow_model_server
```

Please help. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put `linkstatic=0` in every `cc_library` call and this should be enough to force bazel to create static libs for every `cc_library`.

Answer (score -1):

To build `//tensorflow_serving/model_servers:tensorflow_model_server` the Bazel need only `*.o` files. Making static libraries would be wasteful, because they are not needed by that `cc_binary` rule. Use `//tensorflow_serving/core:aspired_version_policy` to build that specific library, or just use `//...` to build everything in the workspace